# Can I assign an include_once file to a $var with PHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, include

I am trying to roll my own MVC purely for learning purposes, but am hitting a snag when I try to load in the view files. Here's my problem:

Front controller grabs appropriate page controller, page controller `include_once()` the appropriate view. The view is a file containing HTML and PHP. When I return the include file from the controller, the included file content appear out of sequence of the PAGE layout intended. (example: I want to display HEADER CONTENT FOOTER, but when I include the view's contents, my controller spits out CONTENT, HEADER, 1, FOOTER).

In my front controller I am *attempting* to set my included file contents to a variable I then echo in between my HEAD and FOOTER in the PAGE template.  But this does not work as intended. I can wrap my view file contents in: return "code" but I don't want the added headache of worrying about stray quotes/double quotes in my view code that could break the script.  I have tried `file_get_contents()`, but this only spits out a string (albeit in the right place/sequence in my template) and does not the PHP in my view files correctly (ie at all).

My question is: Is there a way I can return my view file to my front controller using `include_once()` in a variable? I can't seem to find a adequate answer to this. I'd be happy to add my code if it would help.

Comment: you need to include your code

Comment: If you want to render an include file to a variable, you can use output buffering. [Here is a simple template engine](https://github.com/halfer/TemplateSystem/blob/master/ControllerBase.php) I wrote that demonstrates how to do it (in particular `getRenderedPartial()`). Let me know if you want me to expand upon it in an answer, but it's probably fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: That said, in quite a lot of cases you don't need output buffering, since you can just use a `require()` in the right place. See `renderTemplate()` for a way to do that in a way that uses locally supplied variables that don't corrupt variables in global space.

Comment: I ended up using ob_start() but am curious as to WHY including the file would not work...Can't i place an included file into a $VAR and use it as i would any other $VAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a return value from an `include()`. A lesser-known feature of this function is that you can have a file like this:

```
<?php
// config.php

return array('database_host' => 'localhost');
```

and you can read it in thus:

```
<?php

$config = include('config.php');
```

However, you're wanting to do this:

```
<!-- text.html -->
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Hello</p>
```

and read it in with this:

```
$html = include('text.html);
```

You can try doing that, but as soon as the `include()` scans the file, the output will be sent to the web server. That's how PHP works. Since there is no explicit `return` value, moreover, the `$html` variable comes back empty.

Thus, we use the output buffering functions to modify PHP's behaviour: we start buffering, and then we fetch it and clear it. This is then not sent to Apache, unless of course you choose to turn off output buffering and `echo` what you have collected, in which case it goes back into the normal output buffer and is actually sent.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i just thought that if i assigned the include() to a $var I would be able to use that $var when/where i wanted as opposed to it spitting out immediately upon being scanned.  It was a fundamental misunderstanding of the verbatim nature of the include() function.  Again thanks for your explanation.

Comment: No probs @user1785997, pleased to help.